# ionic 4 how to place ion-range pin at the bottom of the range

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4, css-variables

i want to place the ionic range pin at the bottom of the knobs and make it always visible how can i do this in ionic 4 , i know how to do it in ionic 3 but it does not seems to work in ionic 4 and probably this is caused by the shadow DOM

i cant access 
    .range-md .range-pin 
since it is in the shadow dom and also
    .range-md .range-knob-handle .range-pin 
cant be accessed

```
.range-md .range-knob-handle .range-pin {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1); }

.range-md:not(.range-has-pin) .range-knob-handle .range-knob {
 transform: scale(1); }

.range-ios .range-knob-handle .range-pin {
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1); }
```

how can i place them at the bottom in ionic 4 ?

Comment: I think you are looking for `[(ngModel)]="knobValue"` in your HTML, and `knobValue: number =0` in your .TS file.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib i want to place the pin under the knob and make it always visible and when i move the knob the pin moves with it

Answer (score -1):

```
This CSS will work to visible rangebar pin always.

.range-md .range-knob-handle .range-pin {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1); }

.range-md:not(.range-has-pin) .range-knob-handle .range-knob {
  transform: scale(1); }

.range-ios .range-knob-handle .range-pin {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1); }

and, This CSS will work to move position of pin, if want to move pin to bottom, set css according to that. Also you can remove pin background using this css also.

.range-md .range-pin {
  color: #252525;
  top: 26px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: i ended up using a js plugin but as i remember you can not access the .range-md and .range-pin in ionic 4

Comment: I implemented this css with ionic 3 and its working.

Answer (score -1):

If you’re using an Ionic version and already uses CSS Shadow Parts 3 then you can achieve this by using:

```
ion-range::part(pin) {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 50px, 0px) scale(1);
}
```